# JavaScript regex that matches the .innerHTML attribute of any element

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I am currently building a Chrome extension which has to find specific pages in a website specifically the *Log In / Sign In* page, the *Sign Up / Register* page, the *About* page and the *Contact Us* page.

I am trying to achieve this by first getting the list of elements in the page (which I have already done). Now I need to check the innerHTML of the element such that it is a leaf node in the DOM and contains a part of the keyword, and I am trying to do this with a regex. I managed to build a regex which successfully returns what's in between a start or end tag of an element (i.e. the tag name along with its attributes), but not the innerHTML. Below is what I have done so far (with the example for the *About* page:

```
var list = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
var aboutElement = /^[^<.+>].*About.*[^(<.+>]$/i;

for (var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
    if ((aboutElement.test(list[i].innerHTML)) || (aboutElement.test(list[i].alt))) {
        list[i].click();
    }
}
```

Any idea what I should add to it such that it only matches leaf nodes (nodes which do not contain other nodes) and not what's in a start or end tag? I also think that with what I've done it's going to match everything in the innerHTML because of the **.*** part so I may need to change that as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using a loop to check the `.textContent` and `.innerHTML` of elements? If the target elements are `form` elements, would not have `.innerHTML`, but check `name`, `.value` of `input` elements

Comment: You might have just saved me. I didn't know about the .textContent. I thought the .innerHTML was the only way to get the content of elements.
I'll give it a try! Thanks! @guest271314 and I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Why don't you access the innerHTML, textContent or innerText properties of the elements and do a `String.search()`. Worst case take the element and search for it's children with `nodeType == 3` (text node) and read the `nodeValue`. I mean there are possibly even more ways before you apply regex.

Comment: @Redu Am currently trying with `.textContent`. Will definitily update you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to two of the answers in the comments I managed to solve the problem. I used `.textContent` and changed the regex as shown below and it worked.

```
var list = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
var aboutElement = /^(.*?\s*(\bAbout\b)[^$]*)$/i;

for (var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
    if ((aboutElement.test(list[i].textContent)) || (aboutElement.test(list[i].alt))) {
        list[i].click();
    }
}
```